# Nombres de columnas se ven duplicados en datatable de Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo mi proyecto en el que muestro una DataTable, mostrando las filas tomadas en `_getRows` y los nombres de las columnas para el header en `_getColumns`, pero se ven duplicados.

```
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: StickyHeader(
            header: DataTable(
              columns: _getColumns(headers),
              rows: const [],
            ),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: DataTable(
                // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                dataRowHeight: 70,
                columns: _getColumns(headers),
                rows: _getRows(rows),
                dividerThickness: 2.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colores.negro,
                    width: 1.0,
                    style: BorderStyle.solid,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
```

Acá está el código. Sé que llamo 2 veces columns: `_getColumns(headers)`, pero si lo dejo vacío, me da el error

> columns.isNotEmpty is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto a lo que comentas:

> "Acá está el código. Sé que llamo 2 veces columns:
> `_getColumns(headers)`, pero si lo dejo vacío, me da el error
> columns.isNotEmpty is not true."

Así es, el problema se debe precisamente a que llamas 2 veces las columnas, una vez para el `header` y otra para el contenido de la tabla (`content`).

Define simplemente las columnas y reutiliza estas columnas.

```dart
List<DataColumn> columns = _getColumns(headers);

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: StickyHeader(
      header: DataTable(
        columns: columns, //*Columnas.
        rows: const [],
      ),
      content: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: DataTable(
          // ignore: deprecated_member_use
          dataRowHeight: 70,
          columns: columns, //*Columnas.
          rows: _getRows(rows),
          dividerThickness: 2.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colores.negro,
              width: 1.0,
              style: BorderStyle.solid,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```